# Group by calculation pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe after applying `groupby`:

```
category | item
------------------
A        | a_item1
         | a_itme2
         | a_item3
------------------
B        | b_item1
         | b_item2
------------------
```

On this, I want to add a new column with the calculation: `10 / (no of items per category)`.
For the example data, this would be:

```
category | item   |  value
----------------------------
A        | a_item1|   3.33
         | a_itme2|   3.33
         | a_item3|   3.33
----------------------------
B        | b_item1|   5
         | b_item2|   5
-----------------------------
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible code? I want to try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['value'] = 10 / df['category'].map(df['category'].value_counts())
```

Or:

```
df['value'] = df['category'].map(df['category'].value_counts()).rdiv(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['value'] = 10 / df.groupby('category')['item'].transform('count')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function for dataframes.

Define the function that you want to apply on each row:

```
def get_value(s: pd.Series):
    vc = df['category'].value_counts()
    return 10/vc[s['category']]
```

Use apply on each row:

```
df['value'] = df.apply(get_value, axis=1)
df

#   category    item     value
# 0        A    a_item1  3.333333
# 1        A    a_item2  3.333333
# 2        A    a_item3  3.333333
# 3        B    b_item1  5.000000
# 4        B    b_item2  5.000000
```

You can also pre-compute the values counts and add them as arguments to your apply function.